# Example of number field $K$ such that $[K(\zeta_m):K] < \phi(m)$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Actually two questions:

1) What is an example of number field $K$ such that $[K(\zeta_m):K] < \phi(m)$?

2) In class we discussed that if $L$ is a field of characteristic zero, and $K$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $x^m -1$, then $[K:L] \le \phi(m)$. The reason is that there is an injective hom $Gal(K/L) \rightarrow \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$. How does one check that this hom is canonical?

**Edit:** does something trivial as $K = \mathbb C$ count?

**Edit 2:** my concern in question two is that I see several possible maps. If $\sigma \in Gal(K/L)$ is such that $\sigma (\zeta_m) = \zeta_m^k$, we could let $\sigma \mapsto k \in (\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\times$ (the obvious one) or let $\sigma \mapsto \psi (k)$, where $\psi \in \operatorname{Aut} ((\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\times)$, i.e. $\psi(k) = k^i \in (\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\times$ s.t. $0<i<m$. Why is the first map better than the second?

Comment: By "number field" do you mean $\;K\;$ is a finite extension of the rationals, or can it be a field of positive characteristic?

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? :)

Comment: You could, in a more extreme situation, just take something like $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ and adjoint $\zeta_7$. Also, $\mathbbb{C}$ is not a number field as it is not f.g. over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let's try with $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$ and $\zeta_9$.
2. An element of $Gal (K/L)$ sends a primitive  $m$-th root of unity $\zeta_m$ in another primitive root, wich is of the form $\zeta_m^k$, where $(k,m)=1$. If $\phi$ sends $\zeta_m$ in  $\zeta_m^k$, try to define you omomorphism sending $\phi$ in $k$.

Comment: Dear Joseph, thank you for your first answer. As to the second, please look at my new edit above :-)